# Правописание слов

Tags: орфография

В словаре зафиксировано правописание слова рабочий-литейщик через дефис. Будут ли писаться по аналогии слова (их нет в словаре) рабочий(-)сталевар, рабочий(-)вагранщик?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Да, так как вторая часть -- приложение, которое пишется через дефис: рабочий**-сталевар** и т. д.